# How to make a radio looks like disabled but don't specify disabled="disabled", just using css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css

as we know, if we set disabled="disabled" to the radio, its value will lost in the form when submitting to backend. and radio doesn't have readonly attribute.
now, i don't want to add a hidden for the disabled radio, i just want to use js and css to make it looks like disabled.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<script>

</script>
<style>
#radio1 {
     /* how to make radio1 looks same as radio2*/
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity:0.5; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" onclick="return false"/>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" disabled="disabled"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With Michal and Vitorino's help, thank you. i make the css like this 
#radio1 {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity:0.5;
}
it works fine in chrome and firefox, but IE...
any comments for IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can mimic the `readonly` attribute with `pointer-events: none`, wouldn't it suit you?

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" onclick="return false" style="pointer-events: none;"/>
```

Or you could handle this situation in backend. If the radio is disabled-like then I guess you want to use some kind of default value, just assign it in backend.

Comment: @PierreWang what level of backward compatibility do you want to provide to the end user? As it seems [`pointer-events`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) are supported from IE11 onwards. So if the user is browsing your site with <IE11 just display a warning to update their damn browser :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `opacity`

```css
#radio1 {
    opacity:.5;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio1" onclick="return false" />
<input type="radio" id="radio2" disabled="disabled" />
```

or just create your own style by adding any element

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
  border: 1px solid rgb(208, 208, 208);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
label:before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(208, 208, 208);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio1" onclick="return false" />
<label for="radio1"></label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" disabled="disabled" />
<label for="radio2"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally it works just by the common CSS-rules. So:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    background-color: light-grey;
    border: 0 none;
}
```

Unfortunatly Firefox doesn't support any color changes via CSS, so your only option, that I know so far, is using background-image (using an image of an disabled radio button). [Reference](http://www.css4you.de/wsradio/)

Greetings Mainz007

Answer (score 0):

You can make it look like disabled using this plugin. http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have different ways of displaying form controls, so there will be no catch-all solution to style a radio button to appear exactly like a disabled radio button.

However, you could an adjacent radio control with the `disabled="true"` attribute (and `class="disabled-overlay"` to each radio you want submitted on form submission, and give the radio inputs that you want to appear disabled the *class* "disabled", with the following CSS (see it in action in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yz13LL69/2/))

```
div.radio-container input.disabled-overlay {
    display: none;
}
div.radio-container input.disabled {
    display: none;
}

div.radio-container input.disabled + input.disabled-overlay {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set radio to disabled and when click the submit button remove the disabled
using the following code with the jquery library

```
$("#sub").click(function(){
        $("input").removeAttr('disabled');
    });
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="sub" />
```